# what is the simplest protocol to securely tether a hardware device to a network?

Tags: security, hardware

After the Sony PSN debacle, I am trying to find examples of secure hardware tethering to a network. There are two use cases in particular:

1- computer downloads a piece of software that then uniquely and securely labels it to a cloud service
2- a hardware manufacturer uniquely labels a hardware device that then negotiates membership on the network.

Given the fact that the hardware device might have to change (revoke or service enhancements) it feels like #2 becomes #1.

The broad outline is this:
- connect to the service via HTTPS to protect against man in the middle
- device generates a GUID and presents it via HTTPS to service
- service records GUID against account
- on success, service 'enables' device

But how do you protect the GUID so that it cannot be stolen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to comment here:

Sony's PSN issues started with horrible practices with regards to their QA environment.

First, they defaulted to trusting anything that was sent to those servers using their developers toolkit.  The reason they did this was that the dev kit used to cost upwards of $10k US and therefore they thought anyone who paid that amount would be on the up and up.  However, when they radically lowered the price things changed externally and they didn't account for it.

The second issue with PSN was that the security between QA and live was, well, weak at best and easily circumvented.  My understanding is that you could send commands to live using QA credentials.  Because QA credentials were used, all chargeable actions were approved without money changing hands and the actions were applied to live accounts.  When several people told Sony about this they did nothing.

A third issue was a reliance on hardware based encryption keys.  Even hardware encryption keys installed on the devices can be figured out.

Point is, Sony dug their own grave on it so I wouldn't use anything they did as a template for how to do things.  Heck, a lot of their websites were open to SQL injection which in today's day and age should get you fired.

---

Another example here is the iPhone.  Each iPhone has a unique identifier that installed apps can grab and send back across the network; similar to a serial number.  Some apps use this ID to try and tie a particular device to a person.  However, [it's trivial to create ID's](http://marccodes.posterous.com/method-swizzling-uidevice-to-spoof-udid) and broadcast them, so this hasn't worked out so well for the partners.  Also Apple does not expose a way to ensure a given ID (UUID) is valid to app producers.

---

A third example is mobile phone carriers.  They use a particular ID baked into your SIM card to identify your account in order to know who to bill when a call is made.  This ID is verified whenever the phone checks in with the network.  However, we're dealing with radio signals and any device that can broadcast a correct ID can gain access.  Point is, honest people think that only AT&T approved devices can get on an AT&T network.  Reality is, anything can but they are going to bill the owner of the particular ID...

That said, any software you have running on a remote device that is not under your direct control is likely to be hacked.  The popularity of the device will increase the likelihood of it happening sooner rather than later.

---

Where do we go from here?

On a basic level you associate an ID with an account in your service.  PSN, Apple and others have done this.  When an ID is broadcast, you need to verify that it exists AND that it's tied to an active account.  If both pass then you have two options: either perform the action requested OR request additional verification.

For any actions that require money to be spent, do the additional verification (usually some form of username/password), capture the funds, then perform the action.  Go one step further and every time a bad login is entered, send an email to the user on file.  Further, automatically send a receipt.  These are typically done so that your honest users can tell when something is going on.

Anything else just let through.

Bearing in mind, of course, that QA credentials should NOT work in your Live environment.  Those systems should not be tied to each other under any condition and, quite frankly, should even live on separate hardware.  In other words, QA and Live should NOT share a login database.

---

The thing here is that you shouldn't care about the device itself; just the account.  You can't control the device as it's out of your hands; heck you can't even be sure it hasn't been physically tampered with. (XBox has been fighting this one with people adding resistors or burning out certain components to get past physical security features).

So, IMHO, do a bit to keep honest people honest but overall don't worry about it.  Now, you should transfer everything via SSL or someother encrypted connection between the device and your cloud so that you don't leak ID's to anyone that wants to grab them.  This will help protect those honest people.

Further, you shouldn't have a direct way to query whether an ID is valid or not from the outside.  This will make it a bit more difficult for a hacker to find existing valid IDs and take over accounts.  If you want to get fancy you could honey pot those and track the hackers down in order to sue them into oblivion, but that takes time and resources companies don't normally have.  Also you could log all of the requests that contained bad IDs and use that to track hackers down.

Note that even after the device has been "enabled" I still suggest you have two levels of authentication.  The first is for simple actions like downloading free content; the second kicks in anytime there is a fee associated.  Again, we're trying to protect your honest subscribers.

For the dishonest ones you will have to apply some statistical analysis on the transactions coming across.  Things like the transaction rate can help identify bots that are running and allow you to kill their IDs.  There are others but they'll be unique to your application.

---

This was long winded.  But my point is:

1. You can't secure the ID or anything else you pass out.
2. You can't ensure the requests are coming from your devices or your own approved devices.
3. You better take actions to keep QA and production separate for those building software for these devices using your services.
4. You better take actions to protect your normal honest users.
5. Trust NOTHING.
6. Due to the above you should evaluate your business model so that you don't care what device was used and instead focus on the individual accounts themselves; which you do have control over.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I entirely understand the question, but I think you want some sort of device to hold on to a GUID assigned to it by a web service, and you don't want someone finding out what that GUID is, correct?

If so, there isn't a lot you can do.  You have already mentioned one option... using HTTPS during the assigning of the ID.  That is a good start, but remember that anyone who has physical access to the device can do a lot of things to look up this ID.

In short, it is impossible to completely hide.  Someone can always reverse engineer it.  There are folks out there reading data right out of memory with hardware.